# Python boto3 route53 simple example errors

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, boto3

The script below (simplified, fictional zone/zoneid) when it is run gives the error

> botocore.errorfactory.InvalidInput: An error occurred (InvalidInput) when calling the ChangeResourceRecordSets operation: Invalid request

```
#!/usr/bin/python3.3

import boto3

ipaddress = '10.32.24.82'

zoneid = 'Z3GJIR73GHRHXX'
response = boto3.client('route53').change_resource_record_sets(
     HostedZoneId=zoneid,
     ChangeBatch={
       'Comment': 'swarm manager',
       'Changes': [
         {
             'Action': 'UPSERT',
                       'ResourceRecordSet':
                    {
                     'TTL': 600,
                     'Name': 'www.giganticwasteoftime.com.',
                     'SetIdentifier': 'abc1',
                     'Type': 'A'
                     'ResourceRecords':
                         [{'Value': ipaddress}, ],
                    }
         }, ]
    }
)
print(response)
```

I have previously made successful python scripts to query route53 but I've never written to  it before

I did a pip install --update on boto3 but get exactly the same error with these versions of python modules:
boto3-1.4.4 botocore-1.5.56 docutils-0.13.1 jmespath-0.9.2 python-dateutil-2.6.0 s3transfer-0.1.10

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is not an issue with python libs, the error is coming from AWS. Omit *SetIdentifier* from your request because you are creating an **A record**; if the domain *www.giganticwasteoftime.com* exists it should work.

From [boto3 docs](https://boto3.readthedocs.io/en/latest/reference/services/route53.html):

> ### SetIdentifier (string) --
>
> Weighted, Latency, Geo, and Failover resource record sets only: An identifier that differentiates among multiple resource record sets that have the same combination of DNS name and type. The value of SetIdentifier must be unique for each resource record set that has the same combination of DNS name and type. Omit SetIdentifier for any other types of record sets.